# MediaCodec SIGABRT when releasing output buffers on Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, sigabrt, samsung-galaxy

Good afternoon,

I have come a cropper when developing my Android application.

I am attempting to decode an H264 RTSP stream from a camera. I get as far as preparing to release the output buffers to render the output to the Surface with no hitches.

The application crashes with a SIGABRT (as seen below) when using [`renderOutputBuffer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#releaseOutputBuffer(int,%20boolean)) with `render` set to `true`, however only on a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge (and perhaps the 'not Edge' variety) on Android 7.0.

Unfortunately I am unable to debug the native area of the code. Does anyone know how I could debug this area?

Has anyone else come up against this and emerged victorious?

Please see the backtrace of the crash below.

Unfortunately, I am not able to share the code as I am under NDA. Apologies.

Thank you,

```
04-18 13:48:28.183 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
04-18 13:48:28.184 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/hero2ltexx/hero2lte:7.0/NRD90M/G935FXXU1DQC4:user/release-keys'
04-18 13:48:28.184 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '9'
04-18 13:48:28.184 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
04-18 13:48:28.185 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG: pid: 26350, tid: 26486, name: MediaCodec_loop  >>> <appid> <<<
04-18 13:48:28.185 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
04-18 13:48:28.185 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 00006776  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
04-18 13:48:28.185 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG:     r4 cc222978  r5 00000006  r6 cc222920  r7 0000010c
04-18 13:48:28.186 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG:     r8 c5e42e68  r9 cc2228ac  sl c5d72270  fp b7c2a140
04-18 13:48:28.186 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG:     ip 00000000  sp cc2225f0  lr f2889957  pc f288c1c0  cpsr 600d0010
04-18 13:48:28.220 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
04-18 13:48:28.220 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0004a1c0  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
04-18 13:48:28.221 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00047953  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
04-18 13:48:28.221 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0001d955  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
04-18 13:48:28.221 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000194a1  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
04-18 13:48:28.221 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 000170e8  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
04-18 13:48:28.221 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 000e7d8f  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android10MediaCodec21onReleaseOutputBufferERKNS_2spINS_8AMessageEEE+806)
04-18 13:48:28.221 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 000e3b8b  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android10MediaCodec17onMessageReceivedERKNS_2spINS_8AMessageEEE+478)
04-18 13:48:28.221 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0000ecf9  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (_ZN7android8AHandler14deliverMessageERKNS_2spINS_8AMessageEEE+24)
04-18 13:48:28.221 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00010edf  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (_ZN7android8AMessage7deliverEv+62)
04-18 13:48:28.222 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 0000f869  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (_ZN7android7ALooper4loopEv+372)
04-18 13:48:28.222 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 0000e3a7  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+270)
04-18 13:48:28.222 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 0006b2a5  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+80)
04-18 13:48:28.224 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 00047423  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
04-18 13:48:28.224 26496-26496/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 00019efd  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue lay with conflicting plugins. The [Crosswalk Webview](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) was to blame. We were considering removing it anyway, so unfortunately we didn't trace the problem all the way to the actual issue.

I might inform Crosswalk, but as of now the issue is no longer affecting us and clearly hasn't had much impact on many others.

Cheers.